# C++ how can I solve error: cannot convert ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’ to ‘const key_type&’ {aka ‘const char&’}

Tags: c++

> I get the error for funtion `bool TTrie<DataType>::hasChild(const DataType&) const`:
>
> cannot convert ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string’ to ‘const key_type&’ {aka ‘const char&’}

is it because `.count()` only accept `char`, not `const DataType&`?

```
template< typename DataType>
class TTrie {
public:
  TTrie() {
    root = new TTrie();
  }


 /**                                                                                                         
   * Check whether a child linked by a specific value exists.                                                 
   * \param value a value                                                                                     
   * \return true if there is a link to a child labeled with the value,                                       
   *         false otherwise                                                                                  
   */
  bool TTrie<DataType>::hasChild(const DataType &value) const {
    std::map<char, TTrie<DataType>*> child = this->children;
    if(child.count(value)) {
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

private:
  std::map<char, TTrie*> children;
  TTrie* root;
};
```

Comment: That's a very roundabout way of writing `return children.count(value) > 0`.

Comment: `count` counts the occurrences of a key (so it will be 0 or 1 for you), not the occurrences of a value.

Comment: It's not easy to say what's correct here, since it's not obvious what your class is. What's the point of `DataType`? Does every node hold a `DataType`? What is the connection between `char` and an arbitrary type? Why is your map storing pointers?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `TTrie<DataType>::children`.  As an aside, why *copy* `this->children` and then process the copy?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have added more details to the code.

Comment: The type passed to [`count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/count) should be the key type.

Comment: Do you mean I need to convert const DataType &value to char?

Comment: You need to clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve?  Without more context we can only guess but it looks like you're trying to find a child based on its *value* rather than its *key*.

Comment: Am I missing something or are you creating a new `TTrie` from inside the constructor? Won't that cause an endless loop?